# Where did Facebook spy to find out I was interested in some video game?

Tags: facebook, privacy

So, I read a Cracked.com article about a certain popular video game (that shall remain nameless but involves going into blue things and emerging out of orange things). I knew nothing about that game before. (Why, yes, I *do* live under a rock.) I get curious and I visit that game's articles on Wikipedia and TVTropes. I watch some gameplay of it on YouTube.

Hours later, I open up Facebook and lo and behold, it saw fit to suggest I "like" that game's FB page. Even though I never typed its name on FB, and none of my FB friends have liked it.

Do they snoop my browsing history with JavaScript or something?

Comment: Some companies have adverts that check for their own cookies so if you visit a DIY site to search for sheds and then browse onto a site where they advertise you'll get an advert for sheds from that site. Something like that could be going on, but I'd be guessing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called [Behavioral Targeting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_targeting) and it's being used pretty much everywhere. Here's an article about Facebook-specific behavioral targeting: http://www.switched.com/2010/04/19/facebook-launching-ads-based-on-your-browsing-history/

You can opt-out of behavioral targeting from most major online marketing companies by using the following page: http://www.networkadvertising.org/managing/opt_out.asp

Comment: @JCCyc did you "like" the cracked.com page? The switched.com article says you need to click "like" for this targeting to take effect

Comment: @Midhat, no, I didn't.